# Theorem and formula discrepancy

Tags: amsthm

I have the following theorem declaration using asmthm

```
\newtheoremstyle{MyStyle}{\topsep}{\topsep}{\sffamily}{}{\bfseries \scshape}{ )}{ }{}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{(}[section]
```

Which, when called, produces

> **(n.m.k)** Statement of theorem.

where n is the number of the Chapter, m of the section and k of the theorem in that section.

Similarly, I have a "Step" environment subordinated to the theorem one:

```
\newtheorem{Step}{(}[Theorem]
```

Which produces

> **(n.m.k.j)** Again, a claim.

My problem arises when if in some step I want to just write a *centred* equation using one of these. If I write something just like an equality, the equation either breaks a line or is leftflushed. Commands for centring have not been useful to me.

Problem 1: the equation is not centred
[image]

Problem 2: the equation and the number is also centred.
[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}` environment, which does center the equation it uses. You can `\numberwithin{equation}{Theorem}` and make the Step environment numbered with the equation counter with `\newtheorem{Step}[equation]{(}`.

Comment: It would not work exactly as intended since your suggestion forces Step to be a formula and sometimes it is an actual statement. I need something that behaves both as an equations when just a formula is entred and as a theorem when text is entred.